# Rails: How to disable turbolinks in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

It's a constant headache when dealing with websockets, and it kills my performance in addition to adding bugs. Since ActionCable is the whole reason I upgraded I'd very much like to get rid of it completely.

Comment: caching of elements across pages has been the biggest headache for me.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The following was copied from [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4). It's for Rails 4, but I believe the steps are the same.

1. Remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` line from `Gemfile`.
2. Remove the `//= require turbolinks` from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.
3. Remove the two `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` hash key/value pairs from `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

**Edit: As of at least Rails 5 the last step should refer to `"data-turbolinks-track" => "reload"` as opposed to `"data-turbolinks-track" => true`.** *Thanks to @boddhisattva*

**Edit: As of at least Rails 4.2 you can generate a project without turbolinks to begin with. Just use something like this:**

`rails new my_app --skip-turbolinks`

Comment: I tried removing turbolinks recently in a Rails 5 app(using Rails 5.0.0.1 to be exact) and I had to remove `data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` as part of step 3 instead of `"data-turbolinks-track" => true`. I also see that they've specified the same key value pair - `"data-turbolinks-track" => "reload"` as part of the latest asset pipeline guides for Rails 5 here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: Important: there should be a step 4) -- In place of the `data-turbolinks-track` links just removed, add the first links found in the first box here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets . Simply removing the turbolink links causes javascript to stop working completely.

Comment: this doesn't do it for me when deploying to a Heroku production server.

Comment: Did you have the change committed already? I'm unsure about Heroku, but for Elastic Beanstalk, which is similar, you need to commit your changes in Git before they will be deployed.

Comment: @s2t2 I'm having this same problem with production on Heroku, even after completely removing turbolinks from my app. Did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 12):

Removing `//= require turbolinks` from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` seems to have done the trick.

I also removed both turbolinks references in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: Removing/Commenting the `require` is the easiest way to disable TurboLinks without uninstalling it. Here is a way to 'comment' it: `//= xxxrequire turbolinks`

Answer (score 11):

**If you are using Webpacker (Rails 5-6)**

- Delete this line from `Gemfile` and run `bundle`:

`gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'`

- Run `yarn remove turbolinks`
- Delete this line from application pack file `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

  `require("turbolinks").start()`
- Remove any `data-turbolinks` data attributes from your html.

Change:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: Works for Rails 6 as well

Answer (score 4):

you can also do it when you create your rails application by using;

```
rails new app name --skip-turbolinks
```

Answer (score 2):

Completely removing the turbolinks tags from application.html.erb might break CSS and JS. add this lines instead of the turbolinks if no CSS or JS is loaded:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Step 3 could be clarified, but it's saying to remove just the `"data-turbolinks-track" => "reload"` part (just that key/value pair), not the entire tag.