# After switching from erb to haml the view templates are duplicated on redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I am working on a small flashcards application as an exercise to get better with rails.
After I switched from `.erb` to `haml` as templating language, strange things happen when the application redirects with `redirect_to`.

1. The Browser History doesnt change, the URL in the address bar stays the same
2. Instead of re-rendering the whole page with the layout and the new view, the new view is simply inserted at the end of the DOM of the current page. So I see the layout + the old view + the new view. (But I dont want to see the old view)

Here is the code for the starting view:

```
# app/views/dashboards/show.html.erb
<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<h2>Cards ready for Training</h2>
<ul>
  <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <li><%= topic %>: <%= topic.cards_ready_for_training.count %> Cards ready for training <%= button_to "Start Training", trainings_path(training: { topic_id: topic.id }) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

...
```

After the user clicks on "Start Training" the `TrainingsController#create` is executet.

```
# app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb  
def create
    @training = TrainingFactory.create_from_cards(cards_scope)

    if @training.persisted?
      training_progress = TrainingProgress.new(@training)
      redirect_to edit_training_card_url(training_progress.next_card), notice: "Training was successfully created."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

the we redirect the request to `TrainingCardsController#edit`

```
# app/controllers/training_cards_controller.rb
 def edit
    load_training_progress
  end
```

which renders the `edit.haml` file:

```
# app/views/training_cards/edit.haml
%h3= "#{@training_progress.pending_cards_count} cards left"

%h2= @training_card.question

= render "form", training_card: @training_card

%br

%div
  = link_to "Back to Dashboard", root_path
```

But instead of rerendering the whole page, the edit.haml view is just inserted into the current page.

If I convert the edit.haml back to erb, everything works as expected.

I have also tried converting all view templates to haml, including layout.html.erb. But that didn't help either.

Also: I only get that problem on redirects with `redirect_to`, while the default rendering of views in get requests works fine.

Comment: you have to add `html` part: `edit.html.haml` https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471426/207090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution to the problem, however I do not understand why this fixes the whole thing. Maybe someone with more experience has an idea and can describe the cause of the problem.

After [removing Turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649550/rails-how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-5) from the application, redirection works fine again.